# How to get Facebook Session in second activity In Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to facebook implementation in android. I am trying to implement facebook in my android application. I implemented using facebook-android-sdk in first activity. I want the same in the second activity also. Second activity facebook publish button is not working even though  i already logged in the first activity and giving some error. It's working well if i login in the second activity also. I was fed up with this problem.

The same thing happening vice versa.( from second to first ) Can I work with unique session?

I want login facebook in one activity and post(publish) in anyone of other activities.

My code is as fallowing in the first activity,

mFacebook = new Facebook();
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

```
    SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, this);

    SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new SampleAuthListener());
    SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(new SampleLogoutListener());
    mLoginButton.init(mFacebook, PERMISSIONS);
    mPostButton.setOnClickListener()
```

{// some code to post a comment
}

I written the same in 2nd activity also.
Immediate Help Required Please.

Thanks and Regards,

Kiran

Answer (score 3):

Before doing a request in second activity, do `yourFacebookObject.isSessionValid()` to see if session is valid.

You need to use the same `Facebook` object in both activities. If you instantiate separate `Facebook` object in each activity, in order to get a valid session, you would need to authorize again.

One way to share `Facebook` object between activities, is to subclass `Application` object and store your `Facebook` object in there. There's plenty examples here on SO on how to do this, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726662/store-application-global-data/5728369#5728369).