# Store application global data

Tags: android

Hi 
     What is the best way to store global objects/instances through out the application ?

Comment: What do you mean with storing? Persisting the data or do you only want to access them during the application life time?

Comment: I want to access them during application life time

Comment: u can use shared preferences & onDestroy() clear all preference variable

Comment: @hotveryspicy what about application Context? I think shared preferences is slow

Comment: that i dnt know about it, but another way is by taking static variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android global variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable)

Answer (score 29):

Here is the following code which I use to store `String` in Application Context.

I make the class `GlobalVariable.java`

```
import android.app.Application;

public class GlobalVariable extends Application 
{
      private String myState;

      public String getState()
      {
        return myState;
      }//End method

      public void setState(String s)
      {
        myState = s;
      }//End method
}//End Class
```

In .Manifest I add the following code

```
<application  android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="GlobalVariable">
```

Where I want to set the value of string I use the following code

```
GlobalVariable appState = ((GlobalVariable)getApplicationContext());
appState.setState("Testing");
```

& where I want to Retrive the data I use

```
GlobalVariable appState = ((GlobalVariable)getApplicationContext());
appState.getState();
```

Comment: what about an Object (say class A)

Comment: please look my previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726095/store-objects-in-applicationcontext

Comment: @Harikrishnan R, I have added object of class A using the same procedure.

Comment: This will not work perfectly for ICS and above versions with developer setting set to keep single activity. It will work fine if you relaunch application from recent application list and data will be reset to default values if relaunched from applications. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Storing data in the Application object will do more harm than good - when an app goes to the background and the system kills it to reclaim resources, after reopening it the Application object is recreated from scratch (not persisted). So myState will be null.

Comment: For more information about javaxian's answer, read this http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/ . At the end, it explains how to simulate the application is being killed

Answer (score 1):

Extend the Application object and store the references to your global objects in it.

Comment: please look my previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726095/store-objects-in-applicationcontext .

Answer (score 1):

What about [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

Comment: Android will clear the singleton objects when app is in background

Comment: As far as i know this is wrong. It will clear them only if your app is being killed. Then your process in background but i.e. Activity is in state if "Paused" objects can't be killed.

Comment: Are you need to save state of object instances between different application runs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android